# How to bind property in RegisterModel in Identity without using ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity

I am trying to modify some scaffolded code by Identity.

What I understand is that it is not MVC but views with code behind.

I want to bind a list of objects to a list of checkboxes. I can do it using ViewBag but I prefer doing using strongly typed objects like we would do using a ViewModel. How to achieve that ?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
            ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _context = context;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email est obligatoire")]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mot de passe est obligatoire")]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Mot de passe")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirmez le mot de passe")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Les 2 mots de passes ne sont pas identiques.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

            //Profil = Role
            public string Profil { get; set; }
            public string NomMotif { get; set; }
            public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

            [BindProperty]
            public List<Motif> ListMotifs { get; set; }
    }
}

public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
{
    // Do we need to instantiate this as we would do with a view model ?
    InputModel inputModel = new InputModel();
    ViewData["roles"] = _roleManager.Roles.ToList();
    ViewData["motifs"] = _context.Motif.ToList();

    inputModel.ListMotifs = _context.Motif.ToList();

    ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Input.ListMotifs.Count;i++)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" name="IsChecked_@i" asp-for="Input.ListMotifs[i].IsChecked" /> @Model.Input.ListMotifs[i].CodeMotif @Model.Input.ListMotifs[i].NomMotif <br />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue.

I moved the list out of InputModel and it works

```
[BindProperty]
        public List<Motif> ListMotifs { get; set; }

 public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
        {


            ListMotifs = _context.Motif.ToList();
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
         }


 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ListMotifs.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="IsChecked_@i" asp-for="ListMotifs[i].IsChecked" /> @Model.ListMotifs[i].CodeMotif @Model.ListMotifs[i].NomMotif <br />
                    </div>
                }
```